# Solar charge controller wiring

Tags: electrical, solar-panels, battery

I have the proper polarities connected from the panel and battery to the controller.

[image]

Above is a photo of the HQRP charge controller wired to a 30watt 24v solar panel and this 24v battery:

[image: Battery]

I checked with a multimeter, but there is no voltage coming out of the light bulb connectors (the load) side of the charge controller.

Work mode says "17"

Is this a faulty charge controller or I am at fault?

Comment: Have you tried reading the manual,  and/or contacting the manufacturer?

Comment: You are going to have to open your pictures up for viewing if you want everyone else to be able to see them.

Comment: Mine is doing exactly the same thing. Did you find the issue? If i press the work mode button. Rather than cycle through it just goes to 17 and stays there.

Comment: If you hold down the Work Mode button for 5 to 10 seconds, the mode number should blink. Push the button again until you cycle to 16, or Always On.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some charge controllers have ways of programming the "LOAD" terminal, e.g. to only provide voltage at night (i.e. when there is no voltage on the solar panel). If you have voltage across the controller's BATTERY terminals but not across the LOAD terminals, that's something to look into.

You haven't really provided sufficient details or photos of the wiring to confirm that it's hooked up correctly, but it's not that complicated. However, I would advise you to mark the polarity on the wiring itself, just for safety (e.g. use red electrical tape to mark the positive wires and leave the negative ones black).